# c++ how to initialize vector of 4 empty sets

Tags: c++

For a vector of vectors, I would do this:

```
vector<vector<int> > A(10, vector<int>(10));
```

So I tried this for a vector of sets:

```
vector < set <object*> > mySet(4, set<object*>);
```

..but it won't compile. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost right: even though you do not need to specify the size, you still need an empty pair of parentheses:

```
vector<set<object*>> vsi(4, set<object*>());
//                                      ^^
```

Moreover, since you are using the default constructor, you could simply omit the second argument, like this:

```
vector<set<object*>> vsi(4);
```

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks, Matt!